# rails sunspot date range in association table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, sunspot-solr

```
class Event
    belongs_to :resource, polymorphic: true, optional: true
end

class Planner
  has_many events

  searchable do 
  
    date :filed_at, multiple: true do
      events.map {|event| event.filed_at}.uniq
    end
 
  end

end
```

have these two models and I'm trying to get the planner date range in associated fields in events.

this is my controller for my search sunspot

```
  if params[:starts_on_from].present? && params[:starts_on_to].present?
      with(:filed_at, params[:starts_on_from].to_date..params[:starts_on_to].to_date)
  end
```

but I can't get the record. how can I achieve this